# Introducing a new event to a conditional probability? How is this equation derived?

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out how the first problem in the following document is produced.

http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee178/hw4sol.pdf

## Problem 1

> Note that each letter in the genome sequence is independent and uniformly choosen from (A,T,G,C}. To show that 2 is equivalent to 2', we must verify that the conditional probability of the next letter given the previous letter is the same in both cases.  By symmetry we only have to check the conditional probabilities $p(A\mid A)$ and $p(C \mid C)$ in each case.
>
> Let $M$ be the event that their is a mutation. Then  $p(M)=p, p(M^c)=1-p$ For 2:
>
> $$\begin{align}p(A\mid A) & = p(A\mid A,M)p(M) + p(A\mid A,M^c)p(M^c) \\ &= (0)p + (1)(1-p)\\ & = (1-p) \end{align}$$
>
> > $$\begin{align}p(C\mid A) & = p(C\mid A,M)p(M) + p(C\mid A,M^c)p(M^c) \\ &= (1/3)p + (0)(1-p)\\ & = p/3 \end{align}$$

I am not sure how this equation is derived.

Comment: Could you just reproduce the problem instead of requiring us to download the *entire* pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  What we are talking about here is the probability of the next letter, $A_{n+1}$, given the previous letter, $A_n$ when a mutation event may or may not have taken place.  The author is just being lazy with notation (leaving off index).

It's basically:

$\begin{align} \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1} \mid A_n) & = \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1}\cap (M \cup M^c)\mid A_n) & \text{since } M, M^c\text{ are exhaustive} \\ & = \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1}\cap M\mid A_n)+ \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1}\cap M^c\mid A_n) & \text{since } M, M^c\text{ are mutually exclusive} \\ &= \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1}\mid M\cap A_n)\operatorname{P}(M) + \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1}\mid M^c\cap A_n)\operatorname{P}(M^c) & \text{by Conditional Probability}\end{align}$

Thus:

$\therefore \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1}\mid A_n) = \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1} \mid A, M)\operatorname{P}(M) + \operatorname{P}(A_{n+1}\mid A_n, M^c)\operatorname{P}(M^c)$

And likewise:

$\therefore \operatorname{P}(C_{n+1}\mid A_n) = \operatorname{P}(C_{n+1} \mid A, M)\operatorname{P}(M) + \operatorname{P}(C_{n+1}\mid A_n, M^c)\operatorname{P}(M^c)$